# OBD2 expert in ipad to bluetooth elm327 mini

Tags: obd

Just bought OBD expert on grounds good to go in an ipad (version 9.3.5 13G36)

It just wont detect the adapter from my ipad. Adapter is fitted and red light on.

Am I wasting my time with an ipad and is iphone any different. Help please

Comment: What adapter are you using (link to product may help)? Did you pair the device to your iPad? Is Bluetooth turned on in your iPad? Stupid questions, but making sure of these things may save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: How much did you spend for the dongle? The Genuine ones contain a elm327 chip as OBDII interface and a good bluetooth module, costing some 10€/$ But most dongles are fakes for just a few €/$ with  cheap, unreliable bluetooth modules and OBDII interface. I also have a cheap one. Getting a Bluetooth connection is tricky, and after, connecting to the car takes looooong, if it works at all.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have given up on trying to use ELM 327mini with iOS devices. Apparently a newer version of ELM 327 using a diferent Bluetooth 4 worksbut I only paid 104 approx . I will try to resurrect an Android tabletor

Comment: Followwing above comments do you know an adapter that works well with iOS simple question do WiFi adapters work well ie easy interface

Answer (score -1):

As an IT guy I can tell you anything made by apple is not good for doing real work get an android and use [that](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=en) or their free version.

Apple devices are very picky about bluetooth devices as well and I would not be surprised if this was part of your problem. But I have never heard of obd expert do you have a link?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/bj/app/obd2-expert-scantool-simulator/id1142156521?mt=8

Comment: @Parick However it seems the bluetooth reader may not be compatible with the I devices.